# Replace text using Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, text, replace

I want to replace all the text in a webpage with saving the text `length` like:

From:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed id dui tincidunt
```

To:

```
sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sampl
```

I'am new in Javascript and I don't understand it. è_é

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that takes the string of words to replace, and the string to repeat until the length, then simply keep appending to a variable until the length is reached:

```
function replaceTextWithLength(textToReplace, replaceText) {
    var length = textToReplace.length;
    var text = "";
    while (text.length < length) {
        text += replaceText;
    }

    return text.substring(0, length);
}

var words = replaceTextWithLength("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed id dui tincidunt", "sample text ");
console.log(words);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zdvz59yb/

Comment: How can i get all the body text ? element.body.innerText ?